# Convergence of a sequence of Binomial variable with changing probability

Tags: random-variable, convergence, bernoulli-process

Consider a $t\in(0,1)$. Consider, for $\Delta>0$ the random variable 
$X_t^{(\Delta)}$ defined as

$$
\mathbb{P}[X_t^{(\Delta)}=1]=\left(1-\lambda\,\Delta\right)^{\left\lfloor t/\Delta\right\rfloor},\quad \mathbb{P}[X_t^{(\Delta)}=0]=1-\left(1-\lambda\,\Delta\right)^{\left\lfloor t/\Delta\right\rfloor},
$$
with $\lambda\in(0,1)$. Clearly when $\Delta\rightarrow 0$

$$
\mathbb{P}[X_t^{(\Delta)}=1]=\left(1-\lambda\,\Delta\right)^{\left\lfloor t/\Delta\right\rfloor}\rightarrow e^{-\lambda\,t}
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{P}[X_t^{(\Delta)}=0]=1-\left(1-\lambda\,\Delta\right)^{\left\lfloor t/\Delta\right\rfloor}\rightarrow 1-e^{-\lambda\,t}.
$$

The problem is: does the sequence $X_t^{(\Delta)}$ converge (in probability? distribution?) or not? My initial guess was that the sequence converges to a random variable $X_t$ that is $1$ with probability $e^{-\lambda\,t}$ and $0$ with probability $1-e^{-\lambda\,t}$, but it seems wrong since

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}\left[\left|X_t^{(\Delta)}-X_t\right|>\varepsilon\right] &=&\mathbb{P}\left[X_t^{(\Delta)}=1\right]\,\mathbb{P}\left[X_t=0\right]+ \mathbb{P}\left[X_t^{(\Delta)}=0\right]\,\mathbb{P}\left[X_t=1\right]\\
&=&\left(1-\lambda\,\Delta\right)^{\left\lfloor t/\Delta\right\rfloor}\,(1-e^{-\lambda\,t})+(1-\left(1-\lambda\,\Delta\right)^{\left\lfloor t/\Delta\right\rfloor})\,e^{-\lambda\,t}\\
&\rightarrow& 2\,e^{-\lambda\,t}\,(1-e^{-\lambda\,t})\neq 0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: A `self-study` tag seems in order, no?

Comment: You seem unsure about the question you want to ask: what does "say in probability" actually mean?

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad english, I changed the question  a little bit. My problem is to understand if the sequence converges somewhere in probability or in distribution.

Comment: The decomposition in your final equation assumes $X_t$ and $X_t^{(\Delta)}$ are independent. For a convergence in probability, this is impossible.

Comment: For the convergence in distribution, the (positive) result is already written in your description.

Comment: @Xi'an I believe independence is not a requirement for convergence in probability to hold.  But when a sequence of independent variables does converge in probability, we can say a lot about what it must converge to! :-)

Comment: I am a little bit confused, how can we prove that $X_t^{(\Delta)}$ and $X_t$ are not independent?

Comment: For the convergence in probability as considered in the final equation of the OP, when $\Delta$ goes to infinity, $X_t^{(\Delta)}$ and $X_t$ must look more and more the same. Not only in distribution but for most realisations, that is  $X_t^{(\Delta)}(\omega)\approx X_t(\omega)$ on a large set of $\omega$'s.